# Applying superposition in circuit analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis

The question asks to determine the currents supplied by the two sources in the circuit.

**I don't want a solution.**

just want to know if I apply superposition, I will get the current of each source, however, the current I got does not equal the answer in the book.

Isn't superposition supposed to give ALL the current produced by a source?

[image]

Comment: The superposition principle states that the total response is the sum of the responses to each of the independent sources acting individually. So yes, with superposition you should be able to find the current supplied by each voltage source.

Comment: @Omar...did you consider that the currents produced by each source are not in the same direction? Example: The curent through the inductor produced by the most left source goes from B to C - and the other current will go from C to B.

Comment: Also consider sometimes book answers are wrong....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a network that consists of linear elements and independent voltage sources, so why not? You can apply superposition theorem.

In your circuit, superposition theorem can be used to calculate current/voltage (responses) across different elements in the circuit, by considering only one voltage source at a time; then by summing the individual responses in both magnitude and direction.

> just want to know if I apply superposition, I will get the current of each source

Suppose you want to find the current sourced by the voltage source \$V_A\$. You have to apply superposition theorem for both the sources: \$V_A\$ and \$V_E\$, compute the net current in different branches (without messing up the signs while summing). And see how much current is entering/leaving the terminals of the source \$V_A\$.